# OpenBLAS/OpenMP env vars used by scipy optimize?

Tags: scipy, statsmodels

I'm using statsmodels (for Logit and GLM) and and curious about whether it's optimizers can be sped up.

According to  https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS  (which I think
statsmodels uses through scipy) BLAS looks at the environment
GOTO_NUM_THREADS, for open MP.

It looks like it does, insofar as:

```
python myscript.py
```

... works fine (but provided no speedup), and:

```
GOTO_NUM_THREADS=4  python myscript.py
```

consistently changes the behavior of my program (it hits a singular
matrix error in this case).

Is there any guidance on whether these variables can be safely used?

Comment: Sounds like some testing is needed. Changed behaviour sounds intuitive, but i suppose your observation is a bit more of random-nature. Your matrix is probably on the edge (numerical-wise) and small changes just did the trick. Make also sure, that (1) you can emulate your original behaviour with some setting (2) use a non-outdated OpenBLAS. You can also try anaconda, which should come with Intel's MKL.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to lookup the version of OpenBlas statsmodels/numpy is using?

Comment: Yes, there are some questions about that here (with good and bad answers). Don't have the link right now.